# Issues with sending thru Gmail using Java

Tags: java, email, authentication, gmail

I have what appears to be very simple code to try and send an email from my Java app using my Gmail account.  When I run it, it crashes with the exception `javax.mail.AuthenticationFailedException`.  Here is the code:

```
    // Recipient's email ID needs to be mentioned.
    String to = "fredxya@gmail.com";

    // Sender's email ID needs to be mentioned
    String from = "johnxyzn@gmail.com";

    Properties props = new Properties();
    props.put("mail.smtp.host", "smtp.gmail.com");
    props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.port", "465");
    props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.class",
            "javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory");
    props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
    props.put("mail.smtp.port", "465");

    Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(props,
        new javax.mail.Authenticator() {
            protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
            return new PasswordAuthentication("fredxyz@gmail.com","password");
            }
        });

    try{
        // Create a default MimeMessage object.
        MimeMessage message = new MimeMessage(session);

        // Set From: header field of the header.
        message.setFrom(new InternetAddress(from));

        // Set To: header field of the header.
        message.addRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO,
                  new InternetAddress(to));

        // Set Subject: header field
        message.setSubject("Test Subject");

        // Now set the actual message
        message.setText("this is a test");

        // Send message
        Transport.send(message);
        System.out.println("Sent message successfully....");
    }catch (MessagingException mex) {
        System.out.println (mex) ;
        mex.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Issue was that I was using 2 step verification in Gmail.  Solution is to use an application specific password (ASP): https://accounts.google.com/IssuedAuthSubTokens?hide_authsub=1

Answer (score 0):

I was able to use gmail to send messages using TLS, with the following properties:

```
props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
props.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");
props.put("mail.smtp.host", "smtp.gmail.com");
props.put("mail.smtp.port", "587");
```

perhaps it will work for you.